# linux command line from environment file

Tags: linux, unix

I have a environment file that contains some variables, I run a test and include the file in the test , when I am printing one of the variables it works okay, but when I want to use one of them in order to run command and I need to use the variable as a switch in the command line I am getting the following error:

```
Executing mono /p/dt/cad/em64t_SLES11/aa/ss/dd/ff/gg.exe ping -ws abc -kk
-E- Failed to parse the command line: 
Unknown Args: -kk 

Use -h for help
```

Comment: gg.exe binary have to know -kk option ? Because error il about an unknown argument. Where is your variable that you tell about ?

Comment: gg.exe did know about this switch, this is the output of the command, the command line which use the variable is: /p/dt/cad/em64t_SLES11/aa/ss/dd/ff/gg.exe ping -ws abc $UNSUPPORTED_SWITCH

Comment: Can you please give me output of `echo $UNSUPPORTED_SWITCH` just befor call to gg.exe. This behavior is met with one precise value of $UNSUPPORTED_SWITCH or lot of different value ? gg.exe is your code or a block box ? Are you sure you can put this switch (-kk) after abc parameter ? `gg.exe -kk -ws abc` for example always failling ?

Comment: Thanks, I already managed.

Comment: The issue was with the dash ( - ) char, so I didn't write it in the variable file and I just added it in the command line next to variable.